# Error from importing "from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tf.keras

[image: Error]

[image: Jupyter log error]

I tried importing this but my kernel dies whenever I try. I am using an anaconda environment with python 3.9.16, I tried doing pip show keras and pip show tensorflow already. Tensorflow is of version 2.12.0 and keras is of version 2.10.0. I use a macbook air M2 device and am running this code on a jupyter notebook where I have already installed tensorflow befpre this code.

Let me know if anyone else has encountered and fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You installed a Intel version of Tensorflow which does not work on ARM processors.

Comment: Hi @Antoine, The TensorFlow has not installed in your system correctly. Please follow the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install the TensorFlow in your system using conda environment. Let us know if the issue still persists.